# pyglet displays shapes only after using additional draw command

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

Pyglet, windows 10.
When enabling `sample_buffers` to get better looking drawings I faced following issue.
I see any shapes I draw usung `batch` (in this case one line) only when additional line as below is present. When it's there `batch` content is drawn. When it's not there nothing is displayed.

When `config` is not used, there is no need for this additional line.
Code is stripped to bare minimum, where this behavior appears.
I suspect my config is missing something.
I tried already to get initial config via `screen.get_best_config`. No change.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

config = pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=8, double_buffer=False)
window = pyglet.window.Window(960, 540,config=config, resizable=True) 

batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
line = shapes.Line(100, 100, 50, 200, width=19, batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
    pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES,('v2i', (10, 15, 300, 305)))  #without this line nothing is displayed     
    
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable double buffering (`double_buffer=False` - see [`pyglet.gl`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/gl.html)), you must manually force the execution of GL commands with [`glFlush`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFlush.xhtml):

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

config = pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=8, double_buffer=False)
window = pyglet.window.Window(960, 540,config=config, resizable=True) 

batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
line = shapes.Line(100, 100, 50, 200, width=19, batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
    pyglet.gl.glFlush()  
    
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: I was looking in different places. For me issue appears with or without ```double_buffer``` set to False. But your suggestion works perfect.